# how to increase my blog traffic?

Tags: seo, keywords, blog, search-results, traffic

hi Im a newbie and I have been assigned a task for improving traffic to my company blog posts. how can I gain traffic through refferal traffic and improve my position in SERP. and also how to frame keywords for these blogs. give suggestions

Answer (score 0):

The question is very generic and it can't be answered in a short post.

I would recommend you to learn basics of SEO.

You may consider these broad options:

- Build quality content on your website and blog.
- Share those blog posts on social media, particularly Google Plus.
- If your content will be well researched and unique to your readers then you may wish to run some social media campaign to bring more readers to your blog.

These steps may not be enough but it will build the foundation and once you will learn about SEO you can start some planning and implementation for backlink which will help you greatly to get better ranking.